# how to indicate raw string with regex() if my pattern come from another string?

Tags: python, regex

I have a csv table from which I get my regex pattern, e.g. `\bconden` 

 Problem : I don't manage to specify to python that this is a *raw* string 
How to put `r` before a pattern when it comes from a string ?

```
import re
a =  'de la matière condensée'
fromcsv = '\bconden'
print(re.search('r' + fromcsv, a))
```

result is `None`

Comment: So, in your csv file, it read a backspace character (`'\b'`) followed by `'conden'`?  I kind of doubt that. :-)  More likely is it's actually `'\\bconden'`, which is exactly what you'd get if it was written as `r'\bconden'`.  However, you should be really careful about taking arbitrary inputs and using them.  Unless that's really meant to be a regex pattern (vs. a fixed string), you probably want to escape it so that nothing is misinterpreted using [`re.escape()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape).

Comment: *There is no such thing as a raw string*.  There are raw string *literals*, but that just affects the parsing of backslashes in your source code; once a string is created, by whatever means, it's just a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `str_to_raw` function below to make a raw string out of an already declared plain string variable:

```
import re
a =  'de la matière condensée'
pattern = '\bconden'

escape_dict = {
    '\a': r'\a',
    '\b': r'\b',
    '\c': r'\c',
    '\f': r'\f',
    '\n': r'\n',
    '\r': r'\r',
    '\t': r'\t',
    '\v': r'\v',
    '\'': r'\'',
    '\"': r'\"',
    '\0': r'\0',
    '\1': r'\1',
    '\2': r'\2',
    '\3': r'\3',
    '\4': r'\4',
    '\5': r'\5',
    '\6': r'\6',
    '\7': r'\7',
    '\8': r'\8',
    '\9': r'\9'
}

def str_to_raw(s):
    return r''.join(escape_dict.get(c, c) for c in s)

print(re.search(r'\bconden', a))
print(re.search(str_to_raw(pattern), a))
```

Output:

```
<re.Match object; span=(14, 20), match='conden'>
<re.Match object; span=(14, 20), match='conden'>
```

*note*: I got `escape_dict` from [this page](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65211-convert-a-string-into-a-raw-string/).

Comment: can you please give me an example ? `print(re.search(r'{}'.format(pattern), a))` still give `None`

Comment: I still have `None` with `print(re.search('%r' % pattern, a))`

Comment: @mizolm It turns out it's different for variables, so you can use the function below (check the edit).